# why my asp summation program doesn't run?

Tags: asp-classic

I want to design a summation program that can calculate arbitrary two numbers in range.

But it doesn't run, I can't find the error ~

```
<BODY>
<p align ="center"></p>
<form name = "form1" method ="post" action ="">
<p>enter the range</p>
lower limit<input name ="tlow" type= "text" id ="tlow" size ="10">higher limit
<input  name ="thigh" type ="text" id ="thigh" size ="10">
<input type ="submit" name ="submit" value ="sum"
</form>
<%
Dim i, sum,low,high
sum=0
low=request("tlow")
high=request("thigh")
For i=low To high
sum= sum + i
Next
response.write"sum from "& low &"to" & high &"is:"& sum
%>
</BODY>
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out what is wrong when you don't include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are twofold:

Firstly, your input name attribte breaks across two lines. This prevents the page from knowing the name when posting . So:

```
 <input  name ="
 thigh" type ="text" id ="thigh" size ="10">
```

Should be

```
 <input  name ="thigh" type ="text" id ="thigh" size ="10">
```

Secondly, you need to close your `<BODY>` tag at the end correctly: `</BODY>`

Comment: thanks for answer,the </BODY> is copy wrong ,and in the program they are not in two lines .it still dosen't work~~~

Comment: thank you ,it run .indeed the line error,I correct the format carefully~